# How to prevent sleuth / zipkin to trace catalog-services-watch?

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-consul

I've enabled zipkin on my application and it works fine, I see the traces. My application is using Consul service discovery, and I see a lot of traffic being traced in Zipkin.

Traces are like have names like "catalog-services_watch" and contain things like :

```
{
  "key": "class",
  "value": "ConsulCatalogWatch",
  "endpoint": {
    "serviceName": "myService",
    "ipv4": "10.0.36.114",
    "port": 8443
  }
},
{
  "key": "lc",
  "value": "scheduled",
  "endpoint": {
    "serviceName": "myService",
    "ipv4": "10.0.36.114",
    "port": 8443
  }
},
{
  "key": "method",
  "value": "catalogServicesWatch",
  "endpoint": {
    "serviceName": "myService",
    "ipv4": "10.0.36.114",
    "port": 8443
  }
}
```

How can I disable these traces ? I've tried the spring.sleuth.instrument.web.skipPattern parameter, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that these traces are actually generated by https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-discovery/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/discovery/ConsulCatalogWatch.java

And since this is a class annotated with @scheduled , this Sleuth aspect applies :

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/scheduling/TraceSchedulingAspect.java

And therefore, the property to control the skipped regexp is not spring.sleuth.instrument.web.skipPattern , but spring.sleuth.instrument.**scheduled**.skip-pattern

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same problem right now. How exactly did you fix it? Which pattern did you pu in the skip-pattern property?

Comment: @VandersonAssis if you read the answer to the end, it's indicated

Comment: at the end of his answer he put the PROPERTY to be used, not the pattern. Do you know how to differentiate both?

Comment: well, pattern is simply  .*ConsulCatalogWatch